# Joining two strings to create one variable in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Ok so I have a registration form for users to register and it works fine in that when it submits it enters into my database. I want to add a feature that only users with a certain domain address can register and after looking this up the simplest way I can see to do it is to use a drop down menu with a list of the available domains accepted. My issue is that when I try and run the concatenation function to join them upon entry they are not being joined and added to the database correctly below is my HTML form and my php code.

```
<form name='registration' method="post" action="registerAdmin.php">


<label for="adminName"> Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
<input name="adminName" id="a" size="27" required/>
<br/>
<label for="adminEmail"> Email Address: </label>
<input type="text" name="adminEmail" id="a" size="15" required/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<select style="height:27px;width:5;" name="adminDomain"><option value="@ucc.ie">@ucc.ie</option></select>
<br/>
<label for="adminUsername"> Username: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
<input name="adminUsername" id="b" size="27" required/>
<br/>
<label for="password"> Password: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                        <input type="password" name="adminPassword" id="b" size="27" required/>
<br/>
<br/>
<input id="boo" type="submit" name="button" value="Register" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg"/>




</form>
```

And my PHP code:

```
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "********";
    $password = "********";
    $dbname = "********";

    // FORM HANDLING
    $aName = $_POST["adminName"];
    $aEmail = $_POST["'adminEmail"]; 
    $aUsername = $_POST["adminUsername"];
    $aPassword = $_POST["adminPassword"];
    $aEmail .= $_POST["adminDomain"];


    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

            // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }


    $sql = "INSERT INTO administrators (`adminName`, `adminEmail`, `adminUsername`, `adminPassword`)
    VALUES ('".$aName."','".$aEmail."','".$aUsername."','".$aPassword."')"; 

 if ($conn->query($sql) === FALSE) {

 function died($error) {

    // your error code can go here

    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

    } else {
        echo "Account has successfully been created, please click the link below to return to the login screen!";

    }







    $conn->close();

   ?>
```

Everything bar the email address gets entered into the database correctly.

Comment: is this a typo? `$aEmail = $_POST["'adminEmail"];`

Comment: I mean there is a unwanted '

Comment: For the love of security, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1604068

Comment: that was it Fakruddin, what a blunder. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the heads up Sevvlor, this is just a simple local project, security is an aspect that is out of scope at this point. I understand your point, but the site would only be available to a handful of users. Thanks guys

Comment: @dhool could you please accept my answer.

Comment: I am flagging to close this question as off-topic, because the issue is caused by a typo and unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: I agree CubeJockey and yeah Fak, done.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra "'" in the below statement:

```
$aEmail = $_POST["'adminEmail"]; it has to be `$aEmail = $_POST["adminEmail"];`
```

This should sort out the issue.